# Incomprehensible messages from psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

Using PostgreSQL, I get incomprehensible messages when working with psql:

[image: this is what I get when running psql]

How can I fix that?

Comment: **Do not used images**, copy and paste the error message as text into your question. The link you provided yields a  'Server not found' error, which is a perfect example of why off site links to pertinent data is not a good idea.

Comment: Read *Notes for Windows Users* here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Comment: i could not copy any error message because there is no error message. my problem is very clear : plsql produces incomprehensible messages exactly like the image i have posted. not any other possibility for me to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`lc_messages` determines the languages sent from the server to the client, but it does not influence the messages generated by `psql` itself. These messages are determined by the locale active in the shell where you called `psql`.

It looks like you are using Windows, so you have to change the language environment of your Windows. I cannot help you with details about this, since I don't have Windows.

Here is an example how it works in Linux:

```
> export LANG=de_DE.utf8
> psql
psql (16.0)
Geben Sie »help« für Hilfe ein.

test=> \dL
                            Liste der Sprachen
  Name   │ Eigentümer │ Vertraut │              Beschreibung              
═════════╪════════════╪══════════╪════════════════════════════════════════
 plperlu │ postgres   │ f        │ PL/PerlU untrusted procedural language
 plpgsql │ postgres   │ t        │ PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 Zeilen)

test=> \q
> export LANG=zh_CN.utf8
> psql
psql (16.0)
输入 "help" 来获取帮助信息.

test=> \dL
                              语言列表
  名称   │  拥有者  │ 信任 │                  描述                  
═════════╪══════════╪══════╪════════════════════════════════════════
 plperlu │ postgres │ f    │ PL/PerlU untrusted procedural language
 plpgsql │ postgres │ t    │ PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 行记录)

test=> \q
```

Comment: Hello Laurenz, yes indeed I'm working on windows 10... but didn't found solution

Comment: I thought it was a pb with my powershell but i get the same pb with command prompt,. However I do not have any pb of language not in powershell nor in command prompt but only with the postgresql client

Comment: Windows is known for its confusion of encodings. But if you choose an English locale in your Powershell, the letters must be readable.

Comment: Hello Laurenz, update ! i've upgraded my poershell from 7.3.7 to 7.3.8 and it has solved my pb ! thank you very much for your support. best regards

Comment: I don't understand why stack overflow sanctions me and prevents me from creating new questions right now

Comment: No idea; ask Stackoverflow. Thanks for the feedback with your resolution of the problem.